# Symfony2 - get main request's current route in twig partial/subrequest

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Twig partial rendered by separate controller, I want to check if current main route equals to compared route, so I can mark list item as active.

How can I do that? Trying to get current route in BarController like:

```
$route = $request->get('_route');
```

returns `null`.

`Uri` is also not what I'm looking for, as calling below code in `bar`'s twig:

```
app.request.uri
```

returns route similar to: `localhost/_fragment?path=path_to_bar_route`

**Full example**

Main Controller:
    FooController extends Controller{

```
    public function fooAction(){}
}
```

fooAction twig:

```
...some stuff...

{{ render(controller('FooBundle:Bar:bar')) }}

...some stuff...
```

Bar controller:

```
BarController extends Controller{

    public function barAction(){}
}
```

barAction twig:

```
<ul>   
    <li class="{{ (item1route == currentroute) ? 'active' : ''}}">
        Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="{{ (item2route == currentroute) ? 'active' : ''}}">
        Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="{{ (item3route == currentroute) ? 'active' : ''}}">
        Item 3
    </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**pabgaran**'s solution should work. However, the original problem occurs probably because of the `request_stack`.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Since you are in a subrequest, you should be able to get top-level (`master`) `Request` and get `_route`. Something like this:

```
public function barAction(Request $request) {
    $stack = $this->get('request_stack');
    $masterRequest = $stack->getMasterRequest();
    $currentRoute = $masterRequest->get('_route');

    ...
    return $this->render('Template', array('current_route' => $currentRoute );
}
```

Haven't run this but it should work...

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best solution in your case is past the current main route in the render:

```
{{ render(controller('FooBundle:Bar:bar', {'current_route' : app.request.uri})) }}
```

Next, return it in the response:

```
public function barAction(Request $request) {
    ...
    return $this->render('Template', array('current_route' => $request->query->get('current_route'));
}
```

And in your template compares with the received value.

Otherwise, maybe is better to use a include instead a render, if you don't need extra logic for the partial.

Answer (score 2):

in twig you can send request object from main controller to sub-controller as parameter:

```
{{ render(controller('FooBundle:Bar:bar', {'request' : app.request})) }}
```

in sub-controller:

```
BarController extends Controller{

    public function barAction(Request $request){
// here you can use request object as regular
$country = $request->attributes->get('route_country');
}
}
```