# Symfony2 getting the url of request in subrequests in twig

Tags: php, symfony, request, twig

How can I get the current url in a subrequest and change parameters with it(for example locale).

I have main action that renders the template.

```
public function indexAction() {
     return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:index.html.twig',  array(
                   'products'=>$products,
                   'locale' => $locale,
                   ));
    }
```

In the template I render the navigation like this:

```
<span class="top">{% render controller("MpShopBundle:Navbar:navbar") %}</span>
```

Now in this navbar template I am trying to do this:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}
```

I am getting an empty url because this is a subrequest... How can I pass the URL to the subrequest? This is the first time im dealing with them..

Comment: which version of sf are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.6.6

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165999/symfony2-get-main-requests-current-route-in-twig-partial-subrequest/30166441#30166441