# Symfony route give me "_fragment"

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony project I have configured the routes in yaml config file.

Here is my config file:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
homepage:
path:      /
defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Homepage:index }
page1:
path:      /page1
defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Pages:showPageOne }
sub_page:
path:      /page1/sub_page
defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Pages:showPageOneSubPage }
```

And one of my controller

```
// src/MyBundle/Controller/PagesController.php
namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function showPageOneSubPageAction()
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $routeName = $request->get('_route');
        var_dump($routeName);
        // String(9) "_fragment"
    }
}
```

I don't know why when I want to get the route the only result in all my controllers and in my Twig files are : "_fragment".
I tried other ways to get the route but I just have "_fragment" or null...

I want to have my route like "/page1/sub_page".

If you have some ideas I want it to build my menu. I build it using a custom yaml config file containing the boutons names and links.
I want to compare the bouton link with the current route to have a color on the current menu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - get main request's current route in twig partial/subrequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165999/symfony2-get-main-requests-current-route-in-twig-partial-subrequest)

Comment: Ho, thanks, I will try it tonight. If it work I will update my question to add the answer. Thanks,