# BasePath attribute always empty in request object, working on PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a controller has an action that looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my_route_path", name="my_route_name")
 */
public function doSomethingAction(Request $request)
{
    $myPath = $request->getScheme().'://'.$request->getHttpHost().''.$request->getBasePath();
    $data = file_get_contents($myPath. '/data_folder/data.json');

    return $this->render('@Entry/my_template.html.twig', array(
        'data' => json_decode($data, true)
    ));
}
```

And I create a functional test for this controller like this:

```
/** @test */
public function doSomething_should_success()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/my_route_path');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

But I can't run the functional test I still get : `Failed asserting that 500 is identical to 200` 
So, after I checked the test.log file I find this error : `file_get_contents(http://localhost/data_folder/data.json) : failed to open stream`

As now the problem is comming from `$request->getBasePath()` because always contain empty string but the expected behaviour is return `PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT_FOLDER\web` in my case must return `projects\web_apps\MY_PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME\web`

So, the simplified question: why the request object always contain an empty basePath string in the unit test but it works very well on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Request` object helps you handle the request of a client, that is something like `GET /my_route_path` plus lots of headers and a server that is directed at.

The web server passes those information on to php and symfony, and symfony will turn this into a `Request` object. Symfony has usually one entry point, which is `public/index.php` (symfony 4) or `web/app.php` (symfony 3) which is assumed to be `/` or possibly `/basePath/` (the basepath will be communicated by the web server and handled by Symfony).

Symfony will generate a Request object, where the basepath is essentially abstracted away, and whenever you generate a url (via `Controller::generateUrl`) the base path is taken into account. that's why the basepath is important for Requests.

This is actually described pretty well in the comments of the Request's functions:
[getBasePath](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L877) vs [getPathInfo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L854).

However, this only concerns the public facing URLs and doesn't have *anything* to do with how you structure your project and where that project is located, because that's completely irrelevant to the Request (separation of concerns and stuff).

So I guess, you are actually looking for the *root directory of your project*.

To find the location of your project dir, there is the very base version, where you directly use the PHP magic var `__DIR__` which contains the directory the current script file is in, and you can navigate from there. since controllers are usually located such that their path is `projectdir/src/Controller/TheController.php` a `__DIR__.'/../..` would give you the `projectdir`. However, that's not really clean. The better version:

Depending on the symfony version you're using, you should retrieve the project dir via the [ParameterBagInterface (symfony 4)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBagInterface.php)

```
function doSomethingAction(ParameterBagInterface $params) {
    $projectDir = $params->get('kernel.project_dir');
}
```

or via the container (symfony 3) see also: [new in symfony 3.3: A simpler way to get the project root directory](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-a-simpler-way-to-get-the-project-root-directory)

```
function doSomethingAction() {
    $projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir'); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jakum for this wonderful explanation, but when I call $client->request(), I must find the similar request object with all their attributes and the $client object must simulates a browser, $basePath in Request object must contain a validate path string

Comment: @isom but it *does* simulate symfony running on `https://localhost/`. you can set server parameters on the client via setServerParameter/s https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php#L121

Comment: Ok, but there is a way to inform the client the basepath by passing through parameters table using their key or something like this

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to inyect `RequestStack $stack`and access the main request, after that my "BasePath" has value. This is because I where in a subrequest and I had to access to the top level of the request.

This post helped me to understood: [Symfony2 - get main request's current route in twig partial/subrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165999/symfony2-get-main-requests-current-route-in-twig-partial-subrequest)

```
 /**
     * @Route("/myroute", name="myroute")
     */
    public function myroute(RequestStack $stack)
    {
        $request = $stack->getMainRequest();
        $route = $request->getPathInfo();
    }
```